# Enums seem useless so far. Can you give me an example of why they aren't?

Tags: swift, enums

I'm aware my question sounds really stupid. I just don't understand the merits of using enums over if statements. Sorry for my misunderstandings, I'm just starting out here.

Comment: Have you read the [Enumerations](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Enumerations.html) chapter of the Swift book? Plenty of examples.

Comment: No, what's the Swift book?

Comment: Click the link and have the darkness replaced with lightness.

Comment: Thanks rmaddy. I'll give it a look then answer this question myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @rmaddy for showing me the link to the Swift book. I read through it, and from what I gathered enumerations are easy to read and eliminate mistake possibilities. They can also store raw values and work pretty nicely in switch statements.